# JSON to List<class> & List<class> to JSON?

Tags: c#, json

Hi guys how do I get this to work? I searched in SO and this was the most promissing but it doesnt work either.

errormessage:

> The deserialized type should be a normal .NET type (i.e. not a
>   primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or
>   List) or a dictionary type (i.e. Dictionary).

so how do i split the individual objects from my json?

```
List<class> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<class>>(JSON_String)
```

the JSON string:

```
{
"SPALTEN": [{
    "NUMMER": 1,
    "NAME": "BREITE",
    "TYP": "Double",
    "LAENGE": 0,
    "EINHEIT": "m",
    "EDITIERBAR": true,
    "OPTIONAL": true,
    "LAYER": null,
    "LAYER_SPALTE": null,
    "D_SPAL_NAME": null,
    "D_SPAL_MIN": 0,
    "D_SPAL_MAX": null,
    "D_SPAL_VAL": null
}, {
    "NUMMER": 2,
    "NAME": "KOMMENTAR",
    "TYP": "String",
    "LAENGE": 255,
    "EINHEIT": null,
    "EDITIERBAR": true,
    "OPTIONAL": true,
    "LAYER": null,
    "LAYER_SPALTE": null,
    "D_SPAL_NAME": null,
    "D_SPAL_MIN": null,
    "D_SPAL_MAX": null,
    "D_SPAL_VAL": null
}]
}
```

here is my class:

```
    public class CONFIG_CLASS
{

    private int _NUMMER;
    public int NUMMER
    {
        get { return _NUMMER; }
        set { _NUMMER = value; }
    }

    private string _NAME;
    public string NAME
    {
        get { return _NAME; }
        set { _NAME = value; }
    }

    private string _TYP;
    public string TYP
    {
        get { return _TYP; }
        set { _TYP = value; }
    }

    private double _LAENGE;
    public double LAENGE
    {
        get { return _LAENGE; }
        set { _LAENGE = value; }
    }

    private string _EINHEIT;
    public string EINHEIT
    {
        get { return _EINHEIT; }
        set { _EINHEIT = value; }
    }

    private bool _EDITIERBAR;
    public bool EDITIERBAR
    {
        get { return _EDITIERBAR; }
        set { _EDITIERBAR = value; }
    }

    private bool _OPTIONAL;
    public bool OPTIONAL
    {
        get { return _OPTIONAL; }
        set { _OPTIONAL = value; }
    }

    private string _LAYER;
    public string LAYER
    {
        get { return _LAYER; }
        set { _LAYER = value; }
    }

    private int _LAYER_SPALTE;
    public int LAYER_SPALTE
    {
        get { return _LAYER_SPALTE; }
        set { _LAYER_SPALTE = value; }
    }

    private string _D_SPAL_NAME;
    public string D_SPAL_NAME
    {
        get { return _D_SPAL_NAME; }
        set { _D_SPAL_NAME = value; }
    }

    private int _D_SPAL_MIN;
    public int D_SPAL_MIN
    {
        get { return _D_SPAL_MIN; }
        set { _D_SPAL_MIN = value; }
    }

    private int _D_SPAL_MAX;
    public int D_SPAL_MAX
    {
        get { return _D_SPAL_MAX; }
        set { _D_SPAL_MAX = value; }
    }

    private string _D_SPAL_VAL;
    public string D_SPAL_VAL
    {
        get { return _D_SPAL_VAL; }
        set { _D_SPAL_VAL = value; }
    }


}
```

(I would also like to encode it again later) 
thank you!

Comment: please show the json string

Comment: of course, here you are

Comment: Can you show your destination class too?  As long as the field names match (I.e. the first field is NUMMER) then the deserialization should 'just work'.

Comment: of course, i posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I cannot put comments yet 
First,you have some type mismatch between your data and your convert class:
LAYER_SPALTE, D_SPAL_MIN and D_SPAL_MAX are null in your data.
put try putting your array inside another class

this code has to work for you:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public SPALTEN[] SPALTEN { get; set; }
}

public class SPALTEN
{
    public int NUMMER { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string TYP { get; set; }
    public int LAENGE { get; set; }
    public string EINHEIT { get; set; }
    public bool EDITIERBAR { get; set; }
    public bool OPTIONAL { get; set; }
    public string LAYER { get; set; }
    public int? LAYER_SPALTE { get; set; }
    public string D_SPAL_NAME { get; set; }
    public int? D_SPAL_MIN { get; set; }
    public int? D_SPAL_MAX { get; set; }
    public string D_SPAL_VAL { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
  MyClass a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(JSON_String)
```

Comment: this worked for me! So my class also Needs the same "classstructure" as the Jason string

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the type of thing you want to deserialise, I don't think `object` will work.

```
List<MyClass> a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>("[{some json}]")
```

Comment: Does this answer you question?

Comment: no it was a mistake of mine when simplifying the code for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

To convert it on Internet, you can use the below URL for JSON to C#. I have been using from so long.

http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: i also tried it with a class created as such but it didn't work either (awesome wesite thou!)